# useEffect in my React App keep sending request to my API

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

I have a problem with my React app that keep sending requests (like 5-10 per second) to the API when I use useEffect.

I have getChannels function to fetch the channels from the api and a createChannel function to post a new channel to the API from the inputs.

I want the app to re-render when I create a new Channel so it's displayed right away when created.

```
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react'
import AuthContext from '../context/AuthContext'

const ChannelBox = ({setChannel}) => {

  let {authToken, logout} = useContext(AuthContext)
  let [channelName, setChannelName] = useState("")
  let [channels, setChannels] = useState([])

  let createChannel = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    const data = {
      "name" : channelName,
      "users" : [1]
    }
    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/channel/`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + String(authToken.access)
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
  }

  let getChannels = async () => {
    let response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/channel/`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + String(authToken.access)
        },
    })
    let data = await response.json()
    if(response.status === 200){
      setChannels(data)
    }else{
      alert('You have been logged out')
      logout()
    }
  }

  useEffect(
    ()=>{getChannels()},[createChannel]
  )


  return (
    <div className="channels-container">
      {channels.map((channel,index)=>(
        <div key={index} onClick={e => {setChannel(e, channel)}}>
          <div className="channel" key={index}>
            <p>{channel.name}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
      <div className='new-channel-form'>
        <form onSubmit={e => {createChannel(e)}}>
          <input
            name='newchannel'
            placeholder='Channel Name'
            type="text"
            onChange={e=>setChannelName(e.target.value)}></input>
          <input className="submit-button" type="submit"/>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


export default ChannelBox
```

So obviously I would like my app to re-render only when something change (when a new channel is created) and not my sending 5 request per seconds.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**Update**

Adding a call of getChannels at the end of createChannel works. I don't know if it causes other problems!

```
let createChannel = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    const data = {
      "name" : channelName,
      "users" : [1]
    }
    const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/channel/`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + String(authToken.access)
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    getChannels()
  }

  useEffect(
    ()=>{getChannels()},[]
  )
```

Comment: As `createChannel()` is created within the render function but isn't memoized (via useCallback() for example), it will change and thus trigger the effect on every render.

Comment: I wanted to mention that React-Query maybe an easier way to implement the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `createChannel` is a function. Every time the component re-renders, that functions is re-created, so that if it's used as the deps of `useEffect` it triggers the effect to run, which sets some state, so re-renders the component and so on, creating an infinite loop essencially. You could wrap the createChannel function inside a `useCallback` but in my opinion it's better to refactor some code.

For starters, you can use `getChannels()` inside `useEffect` on first render (`[]` as dependency array) to fetch all channel.
When creating a new channel with `createChannel` return and update the list every time a new channel is created (instead of triggering useEffect to run again). If the server you're fetching from is yours, every time you make a `POST` request you can update your backend to return the channels as the response and update the UI.

Something like this should work:

```
const ChannelBox = ({setChannel}) => {

  let {authToken, logout} = useContext(AuthContext)
  let [channelName, setChannelName] = useState("")
  let [channels, setChannels] = useState([])

  let createChannel = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    const data = {
      "name" : channelName,
      "users" : [1]
    }


    // ALSO WOULD BE GOOD TO ADD A trycatch
    const res = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/channel/`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + String(authToken.access)
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })

    let data = await response.json()
      if(response.status === 200){
        setChannels(data)
      }else{
        alert('You have been logged out')
        logout()
      }
  }

  let getChannels = async () => {
    let response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/channel/`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + String(authToken.access)
        },
    })

    let data = await response.json()
      if(response.status === 200){
        setChannels(data)
      }else{
        alert('You have been logged out')
        logout()
      }
    
  }

  useEffect(
    ()=>{getChannels()},[]  <-- empty deps to run only on mount
  )


  return (
    <div className="channels-container">
      {channels.map((channel,index)=>(
        <div key={index} onClick={e => {setChannel(e, channel)}}>
          <div className="channel" key={index}>
            <p>{channel.name}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
      <div className='new-channel-form'>
        <form onSubmit={createChannel}>
          <input
            name='newchannel'
            placeholder='Channel Name'
            type="text"
            onChange={e=>setChannelName(e.target.value)} />
          <input className="submit-button" type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


export default ChannelBox
```

Comment: So I changed useEffect has you said but I just added a call to getChannel at the end of createChannel. I don't know if it's a good way but it works

Comment: Yup, that works too. If you want to avoid the extra call, assuming you have your own backend for that api, you can return the channles list directly as response of the POST call